# Difference between unattended-upgrade & apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

Assume I need to write a cron job to automate the installation of *security* update daily, which command I should use for better reliability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a cron job to install security update. `unattended-upgrade` do it for you, automatically.
From its description in pkg on Ubuntu 12.04

```
 This package can download and install security upgrades automatically
 and unattended, taking care to only install packages from the
 configured APT source, and checking for dpkg prompts about
 configuration file changes.
```

you just need install it, then

```
dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

then, choose "YES" and let it do its jobs.